# NSSortDescriptor Order Values Less than 10.0

Tags: objective-c

`NSSortDescriptor` is not ordering correct when `distance` is less than 10.0.

Code (Order array by Distance):

```
// Order Array by Distance (Distance = NSString)
NSSortDescriptor *aSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"distance" ascending:YES];
[_contentData sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:aSortDescriptor]];
```

Right Ordering (When distance values are > 10.0):

```
    (
            {
            distance = "11.256649";
        },
            {
           distance = "257.428821";
        },
            {
            distance = "4534.256851";
        }
    )
```

Wrong Ordering (When any distance value is < 10.0):

```
    (
            {
           distance = "252.428821";
        },
            {
            distance = "4514.256851";
        }
            {
            distance = "8.362996"; // Wrong ordering when distance < 10.0
        },
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the issue here is that the value is less than 10.  It appears that your values are strings, and are being ordered character by character.  "8" comes after "4", so it's ordered later.

If you convert your string values to NSNumbers, they should sort properly.